# Probability of computer chips being defective

Tags: probability

In a factory that makes computer chips, all chips that are made are 2% defective. An inspector comes and randomly inspects 4 chips from the conveyor belt.

What is the probability of at *least* one of the 4 chips being defective?

I have the solution, but I don't quite understand it. Here it is:

---

$P($at least one defective$)$ $=$ $1 - $ $P($all 4 not defective$)$

$P($at least one defective$)$ $=$ $1 - $ $(0.98)^4$

$P($at least one defective$)$ $≈$ $1 - $ $0.922$

$P($at least one defective$)$ $≈$ $0.078$

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: At what point do you first have difficulty understanding the solution?

Comment: The first line I cannot seem to understand. Why do you have to take all 4 not being defective into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general,
$$P(\text{event happens}) = 1 - P(\text{event doesn't happen}).$$

Here, the opposite (complement) of "at least one chip is defective" is "all four chips are not defective." This gives the first line of the solution.

To compute the probability of "all four chips are not defective," you use the [tacit] assumption that the defectiveness of each chip being independent of other chips, to obtain
$$P(\text{all 4 chips not defective}) = P(\text{chip not defective}) \cdot P(\text{chip not defective}) \cdot P(\text{chip not defective}) \cdot P(\text{chip not defective}) = (0.98)^4.$$

Comment: I see. So the logic here is that you take a possibility of a given event and to find that chance of the event occurring you would take the opposite chance of it not occurring. Thus finding the ratio of the chance for the event you want to find by discovering it's counterpart and subtracting it from the whole. Did I understand that correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever solving a probability puzzle involving the term "at least", you know you have to use $1-(x\text{ not happening})$. That's how it is 90% of the times and will make the problem way easier. In your case, solving it without this method would have led to you having to write down probability of having one defective+ probability of two defective + probability of 3 defective + probability of 4 defective:
((0.02)*(0.98)^3*4) + ((0.02)^2*(0.98)^2*6) + ((0.02)^3*(0.98)*4) + ((0.02)^4) = 0,0776

1-(0.98)^4 is obviously a neater, much faster answer.